# Deleted AD user, Mailbox in Limbo - Exchange 2016

Tags: active-directory, exchange, exchange-2016

**Short of the long**

I deleted an AD user and their Exch2016 mailbox has not been marked as disconnected.

**Long of the short**

1. I migrated a test user from an old forest to a new forest, and then
   migrated their mailbox. I did this following all of the MS
   documentation regarding `Prepare-MoveRequest.ps1` and the procedures
   for ADMT.
2. User could login and could send and receive mail.
3. I was done with that test, so I deleted the user from AD along with a user that had been created within the new forest (rather than migrated).
4. Just to make sure things worked as expected, I went back later to check the disconnected mailbox status, and ran into some surprises.

**Mailbox Status**

`Get-MailboxStatistics -Database $d -StoreMailboxIdentity $i | select DisplayName,DisconnectReason,DisconnectDate`

At this point, the mailbox belonging to the user who was created in the new forest has a value "Disabled" for "DisconnectReason". The user who was migrated still has $null

**Attempted Solution**

`Update-StoreMailboxState -Database $d -Identity $i`

This isn't affecting any change for the migrated user.

**Status**

`Get-ADObject -ldapFilter:"(msDS-LastKnownRDN=*)" -IncludeDeletedObjects -Properties * | select Name,Deleted`

The migrated user's mailbox is in a limbo state, where the AD object has been deleted, but the mailbox will not transition to Disconnected status.

---

**Attempted Solution 2**

`Remove-StoreMailbox -Identity $i -Database $d -MailboxState "Disabled"`

Returns Error:

`The mailbox 6b7460a9-c25b-4051-94c4-1def02663ef6 isn't disconnected.`

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like classic replication delays. The domain controller that Exchange is using hasn't seen the change yet. Given it is five hours since you posted the question, I would expect things to have changed by now, unless you have some serious replication issues in your domain.

Comment: The original AD delete was done yesterday, so it was about 16 hours between when i deleted the AD account and posted this.